# Special character search in Cassandra

Tags: java, database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a '`user`' table like below,

```
 user_id | user_name | user_phone
---------+-----------+-------------
      23 |     user, | 12345678910
       5 |     user^ | 12345678910
      10 |     user- | 12345678910
      16 |     user{ | 12345678910
      13 |     user= | 12345678910
      11 |     user_ | 12345678910
       1 |     user@ | 12345678910
      19 |     user" | 12345678910
       8 |     user( | 12345678910
       0 |     user! | 12345678910
       2 |     user# | 12345678910
       4 |     user% | 12345678910
      18 |     user[ | 12345678910
      15 |     user} | 12345678910
      22 |     user< | 12345678910
      27 |     user/ | 12345678910
      20 |     user: | 12345678910
       7 |     user* | 12345678910
       6 |     user& | 12345678910
       9 |     user) | 12345678910
      14 |     user| | 12345678910
      26 |     user? | 12345678910
      21 |     user; | 12345678910
      17 |     user] | 12345678910
      24 |     user> | 12345678910
      25 |     user. | 12345678910
      12 |     user+ | 12345678910
       3 |     user$ | 12345678910
```

I did an indexing on the '`user_name`' field,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX user_name_idx ON user ("user_name") USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

But when I search like below,

`select * from user where "user_name" LIKE '%u%'` -> This **works**

`select * from user where "user_name" LIKE '%,%'` -> This is **not working**
None of the special characters are working in Cassandra. 
What Am I doing wrong here? How to support special character search in Cassandra?

Anything to do with indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are using `StandardAnalyzer`, which remove special character**

If you want to keep special character use `NonTokenizingAnalyzer`

Example :

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX user_name_idx 
   ON user ("user_name") USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' 
   WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

Sample Output :

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE '%,%';

 user_id | user_name | user_phone
---------+-----------+------------
      23 |     user, | 12345678910
```

Comment: what is the difference between NonTokenizingAnalyzer and StandardAnalyzer ? will there be a performance difference between both?

Comment: Could you help me in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219277/chinese-language-in-cassandra